# Like button back end logic using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Blog app where users can add new Post and any users can like the post.

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class PostLikes(models.Model):
    likeusers = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    likepost = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,related_name='likepost')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    #likepost = serializers.SerializerMethodField() **I have to mention like count here**
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
class PostlikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostLikes
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class LikeListCreate(APIView):

    def get(self,request,pk):#function to get total number of likes to particular post
        post = Post.objects.filter(pk=pk) # find which post's likes are to be extracted
        like_count = post.likepost.count()# counts total user likes ,besides my code is wrong
        serializer = PostlikeSerializer(like_count,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self,request,pk):#function to add likes to post
        # how do I check if user is already liked the post ?
        likeusers = request.user
        likepost = Post.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        serializer = PostlikeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(likeusers,likepost)
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**urls.py**

```
    path('posts/<int:pk>/like/',LikeListCreate.as_view(),name = 'post_likes'),
```

I am unable to implement logic in views.py module and serializers.py section too. Please help, thanks in advance

Git link to my project https://github.com/Anoop-George/BlogApp.git

Comment: what logic you want to implement in views.py module and serializers.py section?

Comment: Views.py is unable to save likes to post and to check if a user is already been liked

Comment: It's similar to like button in Facebook posts, anyone can like posts only one time

Answer (score 1):

You're serialising the request data but you've already extracted data from the request to get the user and the post, I would therefore suggest using that data to create the PostLike in your views.py in a standard way:

```
new_like = PostLikes(likeusers=request.user, likepost=likepost)
new_like.save()
```

I would also add that models are usually titled as singular items, i.e. PostLike and not PostLike**s** - you can refer to postlikes using the related_name of the ForeignKey field.

Answer (score 1):

```
def post(self,request,pk):
    likeusers = User.objects.get(id=2)// user find for testing purpose
    likepost = Post.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    check = PostLikes.objects.filter(Q(likeusers=like_user) & Q(likepost = likepost.last() ))
    if(check.exists()):
        return Response({
            "status": status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            "message":"Already Liked"
            })
    new_like = PostLikes.objects.create(likeusers=likeusers, likepost=likepost.last())
    new_like.save()
    serializer = PostlikeSerializer(new_like)
    return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.